# HTML "input" form not working with small minimum values

Tags: javascript, html, input

Browser: Chrome Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) (arm64)

I have a web input form:

```html
<input type="number" min="-3e+31" max="1.7976931348623157e+308" step="0.000001">
```

The "step" validation seems to break with a high magnitude minimum value.

If I change the input to

```html
<input type="number" min="-9.9999e+11" max="1.7976931348623157e+308" step="0.000001">
```

the step validation works again. Any min value less than or equal to -1.0e12 will break the step validation.

I tried cutting down the max in case whatever internal method is creating a range via max-min, but that didn't seem to help either.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? This is driving me insane.

Comment: Upvoted for providing a working repro.  But keep in mind, a step of 0.000001 is way beyond the precision that a double can handle for a "step" value (addition) when the magnitude is so large.  There are only 53-bits of mantissa in a double, so I would expect any number beyond about `0.000001 * 2**53` (which is roughly 1e+10) would start to experience `n === n + 0.000001` problems.   For example, you can observe that `1e10 + 0.000001 === 1e10` is false, but `1e11 + 0.000001 === 1e11` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number"   min="-9.999999999999998e+308" max="1.7976931348623157e+308" />
```

> above e-11 this one working , but not working in between value

Comment: not helpful, I dont know what you mean by just pasting text of the input form with some number in the min place. good try though.